# addEventListener not working, always returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, firebase

I am trying to set a new value in my firebase, but I always get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. Firebase.js is loaded in the head of the file.
What do I have to change in my code to get it working?

index.html

```
<div class="container">     
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="txtUsername" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" id="txtBirthday" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" id="txtFn" class="form-control">
        <button id="btUpdateDb" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var txtUsername = document.getElementById("txtUsername").value,
        txtBirthday = document.getElementById("txtBirthday").value,
        txtFn = document.getElementById("txtFn").value,
        btUpdateDb = document.getElementById("btUpdateMessage"),
        rootRef = new Firebase("https://test5421234.firebaseio.com"),
        ref = new Firebase("https://test5421234.firebaseio.com/people"),
        usersRef = ref.child("users");

    btUpdateDb.addEventListener("click", function () {
        "use strict";
        usersRef.set(txtUsername);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't selected correctly this element. Specifically, you don't pass the button's id. Hence you get this error

This `btUpdateDb = document.getElementById("btUpdateMessage"),` should change to this `btUpdateDb = document.getElementById("btUpdateDb"),` and it will work like a charm.

Comment: tfw sitting here for over an hour and it was just a wrong id. Thank you very much Christos.

Comment: @pandakette you welcome dude ! It happens sometimes. I am glad that I helped.

Comment: sometimes it takes a 2nd pair of eyes =)